# Why can't i enter my class in the identity inspector?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to set ExploreCell as the view controller for exploreCell, but it won't let me do so. If I type in 'ExploreCell' and click return, 'ExploreCell' will turn to 'ExploreCel' or whatever I had before 'ExploreCell' (in the image I had 'ExploreCelld' before). Super confused and can't find anything on the web that has helped. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please show your `ExploreCell` class.

Comment: Show your ExploreCell class

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `ExploreCell` inherits from `UICollectionViewCell` before you try to add it as the class for the cell in your storyboard.

```
class ExploreCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    //...
}
```

Comment: If the post helped then mark it as right and upvote. Keep coding.